# Upload a text file in Ajax call to the C# controller

Tags: javascript, c#, file-upload, asp.net-ajax

In my HTML code I have an input type file and a button to upload:

```
<div class="p-2 align-content-center">
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="file" name="formFile1" id="formFile1" />
</div>
    <div class="d-flex p-3 align-content-center">
        <button type="submit" id="ProcessUsedTextbookFile"
                style="margin:0; padding:0; border:0; vertical-align:top; line-height:normal">
                 <img src="~/images/button_import.gif" style="vertical-align:top"
                 title="Process File Returned From Vendor"
                 value="Process File Returned From Vendor"
                 alt="Process File Returned From Vendor"
                 onclick="usedImport()" />
         </button>
```

In my javascript I need to send the file to the controller

```
function usedImport(){          
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!document.getElementById('formFile1').value) {        
        Swal.fire({ title: 'Error', text: 'Please specify a file to upload.', icon: 'error' });
        return false; 
    }else{
        var formFile1= document.getElementById("formFile1").files[0];
        document.getElementById("ProcessUsedTextbookFile").classList.add("obscured");
        document.getElementById("ProcessUsedTextbookFile").disabled = true;
       
         $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ProcessUsedTextbookFile", "CreatePO", new { Area = "Admin" })',
            data: {"formFile1": formFile1},
            async : false,             
            type: 'POST',
            headers: { "XSRF-TOKEN": document.getElementsByName("__RequestVerificationToken")[0].value},
            success: function (result) {
                if(result == true){
                    location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "CreatePO", new { Area = "Admin"})';  
                } else{
                        Swal.fire({
                            title: 'Error', text: '@(TempData["ErrorMessage"])', icon: 'error' });
                                document.getElementById("ProcessUsedTextbookFile").classList.remove("obscured");
                        document.getElementById("ProcessUsedTextbookFile").disabled = false;
                }  
            }
        });
    }
```

This results in the error
Uncaught TypeError: 'slice' called on an object that does not implement interface Blob.

I saw suggestions about appending the file to the formData and didn't seem to get it working

```
 var formData = new FormData(); 
 formData.append('formFile1',formFile1, formFile1.name);
$.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ProcessUsedTextbookFile", "CreatePO", new { Area = "Admin" })',
            data: formData,
//
```

This produces a different error
Uncaught TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData.

My controller code is

```
 public bool ProcessUsedTextbookFile(IFormFile formFile1)
 {
     // processing code
 }
```

The file is a 6k XML format file

I can't seem to find any answers